# why our build does not contain all the required dll's

Tags: .net, build, remoting

We have a .net 2008 application which uses two dll's to remote to a server to get information. the returned object. One of the properties of this object is an enum which is held in a third dll.

For some reason when we build the third dll is not being added, despite the fact i have now included all three dll's in the solution.

at runtime when the code deserialises the object we get a dll not found exception specifying that the dll is missing, for the dll in question, it contains only enums (not my design)

Any idea how i can force the dll to be added?

I can just add the dll as part of the harness or service but I shouldn't have to as it should be picked up as a dependency of the main project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you don't need the DLL.  An enum assignment gets compiled to its numeric value, there is no reference the type in the IL.  For example, this:

```
public enum Numbers { Zero, One, Two, Three }

static void Main(string[] args) {
  var n = Numbers.One;
}
```

gets compiled to this:

```
  IL_0001:  ldc.i4.1          ; NOTE: constant 1 being used here
  IL_0002:  stloc.0
```

The compiler automatically filters out "using" directives for assemblies that are not actually used.

---

Apparently you've found a wrinkle in this, it is very important that you put details like this in your question.  Yes, binary serialization will put a type reference in the serialized data, something the compiler cannot see.  The only workaround for this is to ensure the assembly gets copied into the build directory.  Project + Add Existing Item, navigate to the DLL.  Select it in the Solution Explorer window, set the Copy to Output Directory property to "Copy if Newer".

Comment: when the code deserialises the object we get a dll not found exception specifying that the dll is missing, for the dll in question, it contains only enums (not my design)

Answer (score 1):

use post-build event command to add the dll into your bin directory.

Comment: that's a bit more hacky than i would like

Comment: Its not hacky! This feature was given by microsoft to do any specific work that cannot be handled by .net itself.

Comment: In what way can .net not usually work out which dll's are needed for an app to work? The solution has a dependency on the dll, therefore it should be automatically copied into the debug or release folder.

Comment: According to your question u r consuming 2 dll which in turn use in a third dll. I am assuming that these are unmanaged. This means that the first 2 dll are being directly being used but the third is not. Hence .net cannot get the dependency of the 2 dlls being used. The only way around it is to use the post-build event command

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the "Copy Local" flag set to true in the reference properites?